# Styling <tr> in Treeview

Tags: asp.net, css, treeview

I'm working on an ASP.net 2.0 application.

The master stylesheet contains:

```
BODY TR
{
     background-color: #e5e4e4;
}
```

In a page I'm creating for the site I have an:

```
<asp:TreeView>
```

Each line in the TreeView renders as a <table>.  Each table contains a <tr> which picks up on the background colour in the stylesheet.  *I don't want them to.*

By giving my <asp:TreeView> the following:

```
ForeColor="black"
LeafNodeStyle-BackColor="white"
NodeStyle-BackColor="White"
ParentNodeStyle-BackColor="White"
RootNodeStyle-BackColor="White"
BackColor="White" BorderColor="White"
style="background-color:White;"
```

I can get most of it to render with a white background.  The <td>s that contain data have this as their style:

```
white-space: nowrap; background-color: White;
```

The <td>s that contain no data and are used to indent nodes still have the unwanted background colour.

How can I style the intent <td>s or override the stylesheet?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
<asp:Treeview CssClass="myTreeClass">
```

and define in CSS

`body .myTreeClass tr{background-color:white;}`

Answer (score 0):

```
table tr td
{
     background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Surely this would affect all tables in the entire application?  I can't make sweeping changes like that...

Comment: add a class to those tables that you need white backgrounds for.  for exampple, class whiteTable

table.whiteTable tr td{   background-color:white;}